# how to create gradient text in canvas nodejs?

Tags: node.js, canvas, gradient

I'm trying to create a gradient text on Node using canvas, I tested a code from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp below is an reimplementation and I received an error.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const {
  createCanvas,
  loadImage
} = require('canvas');

const text="Gradient";
const output="./image.png";

async function start(text,output){

let [width,height] = [1280,720];

  const canvas = createCanvas(width, height);

  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  await drawGradientText(text);
  await saveImage(output);
  async function drawGradientText(text) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      context.font = "30px Verdana";
      // Create gradient
      let gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0);
      gradient.addColorStop("0", " magenta");
      gradient.addColorStop("0.5", "blue");
      gradient.addColorStop("1.0", "red");
      // Fill with gradient
      context.fillStyle = gradient;
      context.fillText(text, 10, 90);
      resolve();
    })

  }


  function saveImage(output) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png');
      fs.writeFileSync(output, buffer);
      resolve();
    })
  }
}

start(text,output);
```

**THE CONSOLE SHOWS**

```
TypeError: offset required

(node:18932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()...
```

**How could I create a textgradient on nodejs?**

Comment: If you are trying to do image manipulation, I wouldn't recommend using canvas, why not try this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp.

Comment: I have looked at JIMP and it is true it is widely used, even more than CANVAS on the Node environment, but it has higher complexity than CANVAS for common tasks as creating shapes or text manipulation. However, I'm looking for a tool that fixes the problem. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike browsers, node-canvas is pretty strict regarding the type passed as offset to `addColorStop( offset, color )`.
They won't type cast it to float and will just throw the error you received, as [can be seen here.](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/fe186e5f1e720eca598212fdc6edf16766c21ec0/src/CanvasGradient.cc#L76).

Arguably this is an interop issue, and they may want to fix it, but even in browsers, this offset should be a number, so pass numbers, not strings:

```
gradient.addColorStop(0, " magenta");
```

Comment: THANKS, SOO MUCH, HAPPY QUARANTINE

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of Kaiido https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido 
I notice that have to write the color in hexadecimal number format.
the code now looks like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const {
  createCanvas,
  loadImage
} = require('canvas');

const text="Gradient";
const output="./image.png";

async function start(text,output){

let [width,height] = [1280,720];

  const canvas = createCanvas(width, height);

  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  await drawGradientText(text);
  await saveImage(output);
  async function drawGradientText(text) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      context.font = "30px Verdana";
      // Create gradient
      let gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0);
            gradient.addColorStop(0, "#004")
      gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "#00fef3")
      context.fillStyle = gradient;
      context.fillText(text, width/2 - , height/2);
      resolve();
    })

  }


  function saveImage(output) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png');
      fs.writeFileSync(output, buffer);
      resolve();
    })
  }
}

start(text,output);
```